# custom rpm dependency to a specific version of nginx

Tags: nginx, rpm-spec

I'm trying to create a RPM for a specific nginx module. My spec file build the modules and create the package successfully but I cannot make it depends on the right of the nginx package against which my module was build on.

In my spec file I tried to use:

```
Requires: nginx == 1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx
```

Ben then when I try to install my module, yum fail with the following message:

```
Error: Package: 1:nginx-headers-more-1.12.2-0.33-2.el7_4.x86_64 (custom)
       Requires: nginx = 1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.8.0-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.8.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.8.1-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.10.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.10.0-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.10.1-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.10.2-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.10.3-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.10.3-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.12.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.12.0-1.el7.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.12.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.12.1-1.el7.ngx
       Installing: 1:nginx-1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx
       Available: 1:nginx-1.14.0-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           nginx = 1:1.14.0-1.el7_4.ngx
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity,

The issue is that nginx version his packages with the *epoch*   [see rpm doc here](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/dependencies.html) (ie the **1:** in the begining of *1:1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx*)

So changing :

```
Requires: nginx == 1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx
```

to:

```
Requires: nginx == 1:1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx
```

fixed my issue.